# How to delete or hide header in v-calendar

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

how can i hide header in v-calendar component

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6QJm.png)

like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/saSbo.png

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is missing some informations to be properly answered by I supposed that you were really taling about `v-calendar` and nothing else (even tho, they pretty much all are the same).

So here is a reproduction on how to hide header in a v-calendar: https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-header-in-v-calendar-vuetify-52mon?file=/src/App.vue

Basically, it's just passing a `hide-header` prop, it defaults to `false` as [stated in the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar-weekly/#hide-header)

```html
<v-calendar
  ...
  hide-header
  ...
></v-calendar>
```